# error: use of undeclared identifier 'buffer' C++

Tags: c++

I keep getting this error two times on the same line, but in different spots (same issue):

```
Documents/JoeInstaller.cpp:33:43: error: use of undeclared identifier 'buffer'
    memset(buffer, (char)NULL, sizeof(buffer)))
                                      ^
Documents/JoeInstaller.cpp:33:16: error: use of undeclared identifier 'buffer'
    memset(buffer, (char)NULL, sizeof(buffer)))
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

float pythonver;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    cout << "Press enter\n::";
    if (cin.get() == '\n')
    char buffer[1000];
    FILE* progOutput;
    progOutput = popen("which python3.6", "r");
    if (!progOutput) {
        cerr<<"npopen failedn";
        exit(1);
    }
    memset(buffer, (char)NULL, sizeof(buffer)))
    if (fread(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(char) * sizeof(buffer), progOutput) < 0) {
        cerr<<"nfread failedn";
        exit(1);
    }
    if (pclose(progOutput) < 0) {
        cerr<<"npclose failedn";
        exit(1);
    }
    pythonver << atof(buffer<<endl.c_str());
    if (pythonver) {
        cout << "Hooray! Now you need to install python3.6 or later from source!";
    }
```

In sum, what I am trying to do is get the version of python. I am doing this via a popen and saving the results to a string. While doing this a come across the error.

Comment: `[teach-me]` You wrote `if (cin.get() == '\n')  char buffer[1000];` . That makes the declaration of `buffer` into the `if` statement body, and the scope of `buffer` ends at the end of `if` statement, whichis immediately.

Comment: Off topic: your code is full of un-idiomatic C usage (it's hardlyl idiomatic C++). Try to find a more experienced C programmer and ask for a code review. Your next surprise will come at `atof(buffer<<endl.c_str())`.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but note that `sizeof(char)` is always 1.

Answer (score 3):

There's a missing curly brace on this line:

```
if (cin.get() == '\n')
```

Therefore, the [branch only covers the next line](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) (see `Notes` here at the end of page), which is the declaration of `buffer`:

```
if (cin.get() == '\n')
    char buffer[1000];
// buffer is out of scope here
```

Depending on what you want, you need to add curly braces around the whole block, or some parts of it, to keep `buffer` alive as long as it is used.

Comment: So I would add it at the end of the `(cin.get() == '\n')` then just wrap it around the parts where I am using buffer? Thanks!